# Prevent Qt inputMethod from hiding when button is clicked

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

We are using a `QLineEdit` and the `QGuiApplication::inputMethod()->show()` to have a virtual keyboard for user input. There are also buttons (`QPushButton`) for some sort of suggestions to the user for his/her input, i.e. if a button is clicked text elements are put into the `QLineEdit`.

However, if the user clicks on a button, the `QLineEdit` loses focus resulting in the virtual keyboard to disappear. But we don't want the keyboard to disappear when the user clicks on a button.

We've already tried to use the `installEventFilter()` method and catch the `focusOut` event of the `QLineEdit`, but still the keyboard will disappear as soon as the user clicks on a button. We also tried to call the `show()`/`setVisible(true)` method of the `inputMethod`, but it seems like there is another event or signal fired which causes the `inputMethod` to call its `hide` slot which makes the keyboard to disappear.

How can we prevent the keyboard to disappear when a button is clicked?

**EDIT**

Here is a small example. The gui elements were added using the Qt Designer mode of the Qt Creator (Note that `ui_mainwindow.h` is auto generated by qmake). And it looks like the following picture:
[image]

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**MainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *ev ) override;

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**MainWindow.cpp** (which has the `eventFilter` method to catch the `focusOut` event of the `QLineEdit`)

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <iostream>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->lineEdit->installEventFilter(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* ev)
{
    auto lineEdit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(obj);
    if(lineEdit && ev->type() == QEvent::FocusOut)
    {
        std::cout << "qlineEdit and FocusOut" << std::endl;
        // neither of the following lines as the desired effect
        //QGuiApplication::inputMethod()->setVisible(true);
        //QGuiApplication::inputMethod()->show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: need reproduceable (mini) project ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a solution to the problem!
If you set the focus policy of the corresponding buttons to `Qt::NoFocus` the virtual keyboard won't disappear when a button is clicked!